# Jquery How to target the required element

Tags: jquery

I am allowing the user to duplicate a group of element (they can do this n number of times) to do this I use the below command

```
$('#newRoom').click(function () {
   var $copia = $('.room').children('*').clone();
   $("#accordion").append($copia);
})
```

Each group has an input for the user to enter a title and the title itself. The title heading is then populated by the users input: see below

```
var title = $("#title");
$("#txtTitle").keyup(function () {
    title.html(this.value);
});
```

This approach works when I only have a single group I am targeting, but once a second, third etc has been added it will fail. I know I could change the `id` to a `class` but then on `keyup` that would change every element with that class name.

So I guess my question is, how do I target an element that is not a child or sibling. The relevant HTML is below

```
<div id="roomInfo" class="panel panel-default room">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a id="title" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" class="collapsed">New Room</a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" style="height: auto;">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <row class="col-lg-4">
                <input id="txtTitle" class="form-control" placeholder="Title">
            </row>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

NB: Please note I have stripped everything that I feel is unnecessary, sorry if my reasons for why I am doing something are unclear or if I have missed anything, please ask if further clarification is required.

Comment: I think make a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) is better to understand

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned an `id` which isn't far off. You need to bind one input to one anchor, *how* you do that can vary. Maybe you give them each a unique id suffix or a `data-id`, some unique value you can use. Or can you restructure your HTML a bit so that you can "dom-walk" to the right anchor.

If every anchor was near the input, you could use:

```
$('input').keyup(function() {
  var $elem = $(this);
  $elem.prev().text($elem.value());
});
```

Listen to every input, find its associated anchor and update the text.